# python test framework

Tags: python, testing, hardware

I have to test a piece of hardware using it's provided python API. 
The hardware has two interfaces one of which has to be programmed by 
using it's API and has to be checked if values are read/written correctly by using another interface.
Is there a python library I can use ?

It's something like this:

Test1
write using Interface under Test
check if written correctly by working interface.

program hardware using working interface 3 then

Test2
write using Interface under Test and check
Also try out various range of values for writing within the test at various speeds set through the API
and so on...

A log or results file should be created at the end of this series of tests which details all these tests and whether they passed or failed and some other results from the test

Answer (score 3):

Try the [unittest module](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html) from the standard library (formerly known as [PyUnit](http://pyunit.sourceforge.net/)).

Comment: pyunit is now unittest in the python standard lib.  That page is very old.
http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html

Comment: I like this answer because it involves something that is part of the distribution.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend [py.test](http://pytest.org/). It features auto discovery of tests, is non-invasive and you can easily log test results to a file (though that should be possible with every test framework).

Comment: Through py.test's "parametrized testing" one can easily pass in objects or parameters to test functions which might be helpful in the original poster's case.  See http://pytest.org/example/parametrize.html#parametrizing-test-methods-through-per-class-configuration for examples.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be complete another of these auto discovery test suites is nose (http://code.google.com/p/python-nose/).  I normally just use just straight up unittest (http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html) but I am in a possibly more formal environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a simple test library for auto-logging, and providing you the ability to try out speed, retry, and something else related to the test, you could try [test_steps](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?name=test_steps&:action=display) package, which can be used independently or with py.test / nose platform together.